# Alternative for Html Anchor tag `download` attribute which doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, anchor

I'm trying to fetch some data by making an http request and **download that data by writing it into a file**.

**Here's my code** :

```
var data = {"foo": "bar"}; // I got this data from an http request
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/json;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data));
element.setAttribute('download', filename);
element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.appendChild(element);
element.click();
document.body.removeChild(element);
```

But , Looks like **IE doesn't support download attribute**. This is working fine in Chrome and Firefox. I've tried downloading using **Blob** and all the solutions suggested in Google, but nothing helped. 
Can anybody suggest a better alternative to achieve this in **IE** please ?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan I've already tried the answer mentioned above but that  is not working.

Comment: That's the only real solution I'm afraid. IE has no support for this, and will never have any further development.